# Spring Batch SkipPolicy not used

Tags: spring-batch

I use the setup below in a project for a job definition.

On the project the batch-jobs are defined in a database. The xml-job definition below serves as a template for creating all these batch jobs at runtime.

This works fine, except in the case of a **BeanCreationException** in the dataProcessor. When this exception occurs the skip policy is never called and the batch ends immediately instead.

What could be the reason for that? What do I have to do so that every Exception in the dataProcessor is going to use the SkipPolicy?
Thanks a lot in advance
Christian

Version: spring-batch 3.0.7

```
       <batch:job id="MassenGevoJob" restartable="true">
         <batch:step id="selectDataStep" parent="selectForMassenGeVoStep" next="executeProcessorStep" />
         <batch:step id="executeProcessorStep"
                allow-start-if-complete="true" next="decideExitStatus" >
                <batch:tasklet>
                              <batch:chunk reader="dataReader" processor="dataProcessor"
                                    writer="dataItemWriter" commit-interval="10"
                                    skip-policy="batchSkipPolicy">
                              </batch:chunk>
                              <batch:listeners>
                                    <batch:listener ref="batchItemListener" />
                                    <batch:listener ref="batchSkipListener" />
                                    <batch:listener ref="batchChunkListener" />
                              </batch:listeners>
                       </batch:tasklet>
                </batch:step>
         <batch:decision decider="failOnPendingObjectsDecider"
                id="decideExitStatus">
                <batch:fail on="FAILED_PENDING_OBJECTS" exit-code="FAILED_PENDING_OBJECTS" />
                <batch:next on="*" to="endFlowStep" />
         </batch:decision>
         <batch:step id="endFlowStep">
                <batch:tasklet ref="noopTasklet"></batch:tasklet>
         </batch:step>
         <batch:validator ref="batchParameterValidator" />
         <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="batchJobListener" />
         </batch:listeners>
   </batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `BeanCreationException` isn't really skippable because it usually happens before Spring Batch starts.  It's also typically a fatal error for your application (Spring couldn't create a component you've defined as being critical to your application).  If the creation of that bean is subject to issues and not having it is ok, I'd suggest wrapping it's creation in a factory so that you can control any exceptions that come out of the creation of that bean.  For example, if you can't create your custom `ItemProcessor`, your `FactoryBean` could return the `PassthroughItemProcessor` if that's ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My question was not precise enough.
The bean creation exception occurs when the dataProcessor tries to instanciate a bean with invalid constructor arguments applicationContext.getBean(.....) and after the application was successfully startet. In this case I was expecting the AlwaysSkipPolicy I use to be called but it is not. The step ends immediately...